# Azure Data Explorer SubQuery KQL GeoJson

Tags: geojson, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to create a KQL query where I can filter which locations are inside a *geojson* using function *geo_point_in_polygon*

I am trying to first, obtain my polygon with this query:

```
let polygon = adt_dh_FerrovialTwins_westeurope
| where ModelId == "dtmi:ferrovial:domain:models:v1:acopiotemploraltwin;1"
and Key == "localizacion"
| top 1 by Id
|project (Value);
polygon;
```

[image: PolygonQuery]

And with this data, trying to do another query to filter how many times a location is inside this polygon, with this query

```
let polygon = adt_dh_FerrovialTwins_westeurope
| where ModelId == "dtmi:ferrovial:domain:models:v1:acopiotemploraltwin;1"
and Key == "localizacion"
| top 1 by Id
|project (Value);

adt_dh_FerrovialTwins_westeurope
| where ModelId == "dtmi:ferrovial:domain:models:v1:camiondetierrastwin;1"
    and Key == "localizacion"
| extend lon=(Value).geometry.coordinates[0], lat= (Value).geometry.coordinates[1]
| project todecimal(lon), todecimal(lat), Id
| where geo_point_in_polygon(lon, lat, polygon)
| summarize count() by Id, hash = geo_point_to_s2cell(lon, lat, 7)
| project geo_s2cell_to_central_point(hash), Id, count_
| render piechart with (kind=map) // map rendering available in Kusto Explorer desktop
```

[image: FilterPolygon]

It says it needs a dynamic value, but it is already one. I don´t know how to solve this, because if I try using a *Polygon* variable as string (dynamic) it works ok:

```
let polygon = dynamic({
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
    [
    [
    -22.6430674134452,
    -69.1258109131277
    ],
    [
    -22.6430533208934,
    -69.1250474377359
    ],
    [
    -22.6453362953948,
    -69.1243603098833
    ],
    [
    -22.6452658337868,
    -69.1264980409803
    ],
    [
    -22.6431096910912,
    -69.1257803741119
    ],
    [
    -22.6430674134452,
    -69.1258109131277
    ]
    ]
    ]
    });
adt_dh_FerrovialTwins_westeurope
| where ModelId == "dtmi:ferrovial:domain:models:v1:camiondetierrastwin;1"
    and Key == "localizacion"
| extend lon=(Value).geometry.coordinates[0], lat= (Value).geometry.coordinates[1]
| project todecimal(lon), todecimal(lat), Id
| where geo_point_in_polygon(lon, lat, polygon)
| summarize count() by Id, hash = geo_point_to_s2cell(lon, lat, 7)
| project geo_s2cell_to_central_point(hash), Id, count_
| render piechart with (kind=map) // map rendering available in Kusto Explorer desktop
```

[image: PolygonOK]

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: P.S. The language is called KQL. Not sure what you mean by KustoSQL (ADX/Kusto does support some basic SQL based on T-SQL, but it's not what you're using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal, reproducible example:

```
let polygon = print dynamic({"type": "Polygon","coordinates": []});
print geo_point_in_polygon(0, 0, polygon)
```

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVEoyM%20pTM/PU7BVKCjKzCtRSKnMS8zNTNaoViqpLEhVslJQCoCoUNJRSs7PL0rJzEssSS0GSkTH1mpac0F0pafmxxfkA1nxmXnxUCM1DHQUgAjK0wQA9lRQNm0AAAA=)

You shared the IntelliSense error:

> A value of type dynamic expected

However, you didn't share the run-time error:

> Failed to resolve **scalar** expression named 'polygon'

As the error suggests, the function expects a scalar as an argument.
Your tabular expression can be converted to scalar using the [toscalar()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/toscalarfunction) function.

```
let polygon = toscalar(print dynamic({"type": "Polygon","coordinates": []}));
print geo_point_in_polygon(0, 0, polygon)
```

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVEoyM%20pTM/PU7BVKMkvTk7MSSzSKCjKzCtRSKnMS8zNTNaoViqpLEhVslJQCoAoVdJRSs7PL0rJzEssSS0GSkTH1mpqWnNBtKWn5scX5ANZ8Zl58VDDNQx0FIAIytMEACeTVBJ3AAAA)